# Scheme / Simple Recursion Questions

Tags: scheme

In *Concrete Abstractions*, there is this example of recursion:

```
(define subtract-the-first (lambda (n)
                             (if (= n 0) 0
                                 (- (subtract-the-first (- n 1)) n))))
```

This I understand. For instance, if n = 3, this function evaluates to:
`(- (+ (+ (+ 1) 2) 3))`   -> -6

However, in one of the follow-up examples, one is supposed to explain why it's not possible to switch the order of operations. For instance, let's look at this:

```
(define subtract-the-first2 (lambda (n)
                             (if (= n 0) 0
                                 (- n (subtract-the-first2 (- n 1))))))
```

If I call (subtract-the-first2 4), the result is 2. However, I don't quite understand the evaluation. Obviously, I am making a mistake here, because see this:
`(- 4 (+ 3 (+ 2 (+ 1))) )`, which is equal to `(- 4 6)` and thus evaluates to -2.

I appreciate any pointers as I've been banging me head against the wall for half an hour or so already...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the evaluation of this function by adding some `semiquote`s and `unquote`s:

```
(define subtract-the-first2 (lambda (n)
                              (if (= n 0) 0
                                `(- ,n ,(subtract-the-first2 (- n 1))))))
```

Then evaluate:

```
> (subtract-the-first2 4)
(- 4 (- 3 (- 2 (- 1 0))))
```

This evaluates to `2`. (I don't see where you got the pluses...)

Comment: Thank you very much! I made some wrong assumption about the evaluation, but it's all clear now.